# Relation between homology class and homology groups and betti numbers

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading about algebraic topology from various different sources. I found a lot of material on calculating homology groups using chain complexes and computing their betti numbers. I think I have some understanding of these concepts now. But I want to understand the relation of homology class with homology groups. Most of the tutorials don't include that information.

Can homology classes be defined using homology groups? Or both correspond to different information?

In a graph, how can I know that two trajectories belong to the same homology class?

Also, are the homology and homotopy classes same? I understand two loops belong to the same homotopy class if one can be continuously deformed into the another, what does homology class signify?

Comment: Homology classes are elements of homology groups. Homology is the abelianization of homotopy.

Comment: Is there a formal definition of homology class like there is for homotopy classes? From your comment I understand that number of homology classes would be less than homotopy classes because of commutativity.

Comment: Sure, if two trajectories $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ have the same starting and ending points, then consider the homotopy class of the loop formed by the concatenation of $\gamma_1$ and the reverse of $\gamma_2$. If this is trivial in the Abelianization (I.e. lies in the commutator subgroup of the Homotopy group), then $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ lie in the same Homology class. Alternatively, you can think of homology classes as classes of cycles with equivalence induced by boundaries, but this is just restating the definition.

Comment: I am a little worried that by "various sources" you mean Wikipedia and its ilk. If you want to learn a little algebraic topology, you should pick one of the many good textbooks and learn by studying from it.

Comment: I understand your concern. I referred to some lecture notes and some Youtube lecture series. I am studying from Hatcher's book these days.

Comment: The formal definition of a homology class is: an element of a homology group.